# Partial Differential Equation with weird behaviour

Tags: partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I came across the following PDE:
$$
\partial_xf(x,y)+\partial_y(f(x,y))=\gamma(x)(f^2(x,y)-f(0,y))
$$
Assume that $f$ is a well behaved function and $\gamma(x)$ is given and I have the initial conditions $f(0,y)=g(y)$.

I have worked several times with the characteristic curves method and I know the separation-variables methods, I attacked it with Laplace and Fourier transforms but nothing got out of them.

Comment: any context? Why do you study this PDE?

Comment: I had a Functional Derivative Equation, I applied the generalized characteristic method to it. As a result, you don't have ODE anymore, you have ODE and one PDE. This is the PDE.

Comment: For any $x, y$ set $h(t) = f(t, y-x+t)$, one has an ODE of the form $h'(t) = \gamma(t) (h^2 -g(y-x+t))$. It seems that the best you have.